# 10*10 table, cell's neighbor count

Tags: c#, cell, drawrectangle

So I've got this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Table t = new Table();
    }
}
class Cell
{
    Point position;
    const int SIZE = 20;
    Cell[] neighbors;
    public Cell(Point position, Random r)
    {
        this.position = position;
        Visualisation(r);
    }
    void Visualisation(Random r)
    {
        Graphics paper= Form1.ActiveForm.CreateGraphics();
        paper.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red), position.X, position.Y, SIZE, SIZE);
    }
}
class Table
{
    Cell[] table = new Cell[100];
    public Table()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            table[i] = new Cell(new Point(i % 10 * 20 + 40, i / 10 * 20 + 40), r);
        }
    }
```

And i would write the number to the all cells, how many neighbors got each cells.
How should I do that? 
Cella[] szomszedok; is the part where i should count how many neighbors got each cells.
The goal what i need in the cells:

```
3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 3
5 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 5
5 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 5
5 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 5
5 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 5
5 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 5
5 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 5
5 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 5
5 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 5
3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 3
```

Comment: Hey. I would suggest, that you code in English. This will make it much easier for people to work on your code. It's really hard to keep in mind what rajzlap is again, if that word in not part of you mother language.

Comment: Edited, i hope it much understandable now. Thanks for tip,

Comment: Do diagonals count as neighbours?

Comment: No just other cells.

Comment: So, do you want to store an array of the neighboring cells of just the number of neighboring cells?

Comment: Since neighbors is an array of Cell objects (and not, say, an integer), you don't want the number, you want the neighboring cells themselves. Right?

Comment: Yes, i would in array, and I would show it too in the cells, but i know its a bit complicated, cause its not a table, its just a drawing paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible approaches for this.

A naive approach would be to create an `GetIndex(int x, int y)` method to get the index to use for `table[]`. Let it return `-1` for a position that is not on the grid. Then create a `GetCell(int x, int y)` method that calls `GetIndex()` and returns the given cell, or `null`  for a position that is not on the grid.

Now you can count the neighbors for a given cell at `[x, y]` by introducing a method that finds the neighbors:

```
public List<Cell> GetNeighbors(int x, int y)
{
    var neighbors = new List<Cell>();
    neighbors.Add(GetCell(x - 1, y - 1));
    neighbors.Add(GetCell(x + 0, y - 1));
    neighbors.Add(GetCell(x + 1, y - 1));
    // ...
    neighbors.Add(GetCell(x + 1, y + 1));

    return neighbors;
}
```

Then to count a cell's neighbors, just count `table.GetNeighbors(x, y).Count(n => n != null)`.